# FTP .jpg image upload failed

Tags: ftp

I used command line tool 'ftp' and following code to upload a image 'location.jpg' to my FTP server.

```
ftp> put location.jpg 
local: location.jpg remote: location.jpg
227 Entering Passive Mode (xxx).
125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.
226 Transfer complete.
98050 bytes sent in 0.0608 secs (1612.40 Kbytes/sec)
```

But I can not open my image on server(only show me dark background), and it will be broken while I download it. (Viewer given massage 'Error interpreting JPEG image file (JPEG datastream contains no image)')

How can I put my image on?

Answer (score 0):

In most systems the default transfer mode is ASCII, which doesn't work well with image files.

Set the transfer to binary mode by typing binary before your upload and download commands.

Comment: syxbyi, Did you try setting the transfer type to Binary? Are you still having issues?